# How to delete from apache phoenix querying by fields not in every index

Tags: apache-phoenix

I try to execute statement

```
DELETE FROM statistics WHERE statistic_id is null
```

and geting error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 1027 (42Y86): All columns referenced in a WHERE clause must be available in every index for a table with immutable rows. tableName=STATISTICS
at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:386)
at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:145)
at org.apache.phoenix.compile.DeleteCompiler.compile(DeleteCompiler.java:389)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableDeleteStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:553)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableDeleteStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:541)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:303)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:296)
at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:294)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.execute(PhoenixStatement.java:1254)
at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:822)
at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:808)
at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:681)
at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292)
```

my primary key is on field ID and I've secondary key on STATISTIC_ID

Comment: finally I resolved this by change table option to IMMUTABLE_ROWS=false

Answer (score 1):

Phoenix require [1] that when you delete something from table with immutable rows, rows to delete should be filtered by *all* indexed columns. The one way to do so is to disable offending indices by

```
ALTER INDEX index_name ON table_name DISABLE;
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;
```

And afterwards rebuild disabled indices:

```
ALTER INDEX index_name ON table_name REBUILD;
```

However, keep in mind that this operation takes significant amount of time and resources.

[1] https://phoenix.apache.org/secondary_indexing.html#Immutable_Tables